# Double underline for questions in user profile summary on some sites

Tags: bug, profile-page

Noticed this today: ([Source](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/805/glen-b))

> [image]

- The two lines appear only when hovering the question text.
- Hovering the cell around the link will produce one line.
- The text is "jumpy" when hovering, though it's too minor to be reported on its own.
- Happens only in Questions section of profile summary tab.
- Happens only in some sites, Stack Overflow for example is OK.

Observed in Chrome 31, IE 10 and Firefox 25.

Looks like underline is being applied to both the anchor element and its parent table cell element.